# problem in port forwarding after connect SSH using (ssh2)

Tags: node.js, ssh, proxy, electron

After create the ssh connection, I want to forward it on a certain port and then pass all data traffic through it by proxying.

```
    const conn = new Client();
    const sshConfig: ConnectConfig = {
      host: sshIp,
      port: sshPort,
      username: sshUsername,
      password: sshPassword,
    };

    const StaticIP = "127.0.0.1";

    conn.on("ready", () => {
      console.log("ssh connected!");

      conn.forwardOut(StaticIP, 4567, sshIp, sshPort, (err, stream) => {
        if (err) {
          return;
        }

        connectToProxy(StaticIP, 4567);

        stream.on("data", (data) => {
          console.log(`received data: ${data}`);
        });

        stream.on("close", () => {
          console.log("connection is closed!");
        });
      });
    });
    console.log("ssh connecting..");
    conn.connect(sshConfig);
```

Can anyone tell me where the problem is in my code?
The ssh connection is established, but the forwarding port does not work properly and does not pass the traffic.

Comment: What do you mean "does not work properly"? How are these applications being configured to use the port forwarding? What happens when applications try to use it? Do you get any error messages? What do the errors say?

Comment: @Kenster After this, I will apply a proxy to the entire system, which will read from 127.0.0.1 with port 4567. When I go to the browser and open a website, it does not open at all. It seems that the port forwarding is not done correctly.It doesn't give any particular error, but it doesn't work either

Comment: ssh connecting..
ssh connected!
proxy is set successfully.
received data: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.7